# Entity Framework Code First Child Navigation Property null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a project using Entity Framework Code First version 6 with **Lazy loading**.  At the model level it has a Course which has Modules.  The course class is declared as follows:

```
public class Course : BaseEntity
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public int Revision { get; set; }

    //private IList<Module> _modules;
    //public virtual IList<Module> Modules
    //{
    //    get { return _modules ?? (_modules = new List<Module>()); }
    //    set { _modules = value; }
    //}
    public virtual ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}
```

My Module class is declared as follows:

```
public class Module : BaseEntity
{
    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public Int64 CourseID { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

    public String Title { get; set; }
    public Int32 SequenceNo { get; set; }

    public override string HumanDisplay
    {
        get { return Title; }
    }

    private IList<ModuleItem> _items;
    public virtual IList<ModuleItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items ?? (_items = new List<ModuleItem>()); }
        set { _items = value; }
    }


}
```

The BaseEntity class they both inherit from is just to reduce code duplication for common application properties.  It declares the primary key for all entities as such:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Int64 Id { get; set; }
```

I can include more details on it if relevant but I can't see how they'd interfere and there is a bunch of off topic framework stuff there.

When I load the view to edit a Course that already exists in the database the Modules property of the Course is always null when consumed in an MVC view **even when there should be records**.  For example editing course with id 3 has a null Modules property despite the fact there are several modules with a Course ID of 3.

The inverse navigation of the relationship **DOES** however work.  If I go to the view to edit Module id 5 it's Course property is set as expected and I can access the Course values.  This module is linked to Course ID 3.

My Entity Framework Code First is using default configuration i.e. Lazy Loading is enabled.  I have verified this by inspecting the debugger values of the DBContext but also that explains why the Course property is working from the Module to the Course automatically.

What are the possible causes of the relationship working from the Module to the Course but not from the Course to the Modules collection?

As you can see from the commented code in the Course class, I had it handling the null situation previously by ensuring the Modules property was never null but that only matters when there are no Modules for a course which isn't the case here so I have tried changing this back to the basic ICollection property to rule it out as a problem.

I have also debugged when the DBContext is being disposed and it is definitely after the view code has run so there is no danger of the DBContext being disposed before the Collection is accessed.

I am not interested in explicitly using Include statements.  I want to use lazy loading and EF to automatically get the data and I am aware of the implications this has on performance etc.

Ideally I don't want to have to describe the relationship to Entity Framework beyond the use of the properties above. If I have to I can, but please explain why as I'm sure I have successfully done this simple parent - Child, 1 - many relationship before without problem.

**UPDATE 1**

Controller action code is as follows

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(long id = 0)
    {
        if (Session.GetUser().GetCombinedPrivilegeForEntity(Entity).CanRead)
        {
            String saveSuccess = TempData["successMessage"] as String;
            currentModel = GetID(id);

            if (currentModel == null)
                throw new RecordNotFoundException(id, typeof(Model).Name);

            currentVM = Activator.CreateInstance<ViewModel>();

            currentVM.Model = currentModel;
            currentVM.DB = DB;
            currentVM.ViewMode = ViewMode.Edit;
            currentVM.SuccessMessage = saveSuccess;
            SetViewModelPermissions();

            //Cache.AddEntry(Session.SessionID, Entity, currentVM.Model.Id, currentVM);
            if (currentModel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            if (ForcePartial || Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return PartialView(GetViewName("Edit"), currentVM);

            else
                return View(GetViewName("Edit"), MasterName, currentVM);

        }
        else
        {
            throw new PermissionException("read", Entity);
        }
    }
```

If I debug after the following line and inspect the property it gets automically populated as expected.

```
currentModel = GetID(id);
```

As @Zaphod commented it looks like the DB connection is closed before the view starts rendering.  I don't understand why that happens since we're still server side and haven't yet returned the markup to the browser.  Is there a way to enable lazy loading within views and only close the connection when the controller is disposed?

**Update 2**

The actual GetID code:

```
 protected virtual Model GetID(long id = 0)
 {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
 }
```

DbSet is correspondingly set in the constructor of the Controller to point to the DbSet on the DbContext:

```
public CourseController()
        : base()
    {
        this.DbSet = DB.Courses;
    }
```

I can't see how the DbSet would somehow break queries between the last line of the controller action calling the view and the view starting to run.

**Update 3**

I should have included details of where the DbContext is created which is in the inherited controller constructor:

```
public ApplicationCRUDController()
        : base()
    {
       this.DB = eLearn.Models.DbContext.CreateContext(Session);
    }
```

This is only disposed once in the inherited controller's Dispose method which is not being called until AFTER the view has rendered:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (DB != null)
            DB.Dispose();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

I still don't understand why the inverse relationship scenario would work fine as it should be lazy loading in the view for it as it all uses the same framework.

Comment: You'll need to show some code of how you're loading the course.  Using exactly the classes you've provided here, lazy loading works both ways for me.  I would suggest writing a small test program to demonstrate what doesn't work.

Comment: Those classes definitely look like they're fine to me. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: most likely the nav property has not been populated before you close the connection (ie send data to the view). As @Richard suggested, post the code where you retrieve the entity and pass it to the view (or viewmodel)

Comment: @Zaphod I think you guys are onto something because if I inspect the property in the controller action the property is populated and the view renders correctly.  I didn't know the db connection was automatically closed before the view was called.  It's not calling Dispose on the controller.  Do you know what causes that?  I will post update shortly

Comment: @Richard I have included the controller code although there's a bunch of extra framework stuff that isn't relevant there.  Please see my update about inspecting the property in the controller action populating the property and it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a rogue adding of the model object to the DbContext DbSet in the controller framework's OnActionExecuted:

```
//We seem to need to add the model to the context because the context it was added on has been disposed....for some reason.
DbSet.Add(vm.Model);
```

Taking this Add call out solves the problem.  I still don't understand why it breaks the relationship in one direction only.  The other problem is that code was put in to fix another problem so that will be broken again but I don't know what that was so will just have to go with it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a generic controller, but it doesn't show how the entity is loaded.  If your connection is disposed before the view is executed, you will not be able to use lazy loading.  For example, consider the following:

```
Course firstCourse;
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    firstCourse = context.Courses.First();
    Console.WriteLine("Course {0} has {1} modules", firstCourse.Title,
        firstCourse.Modules.Count);
}
```

This works fine.  Rearrange things though...

```
Course firstCourse;
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    firstCourse = context.Courses.First();
}
Console.WriteLine("Course {0} has {1} modules", firstCourse.Title, 
    firstCourse.Modules.Count);    // ObjectDisposedException when Modules tries to lazy load
```

To make this work in MVC you have a number of choices:

- Use Includes, or explicit lazy loading to populate the module
- Ensure the DbContext doesn't get disposed until the end of the request (if you're using IoC, something like RequestLifetimeScope in Autofac).
- Use a Model / ViewModel approach where your viewmodel will be populated while the connection is open

Comment: thanks but I don't dispose the context.  I set a DbSet property on the view model for LINQ queries to be written against.  Please see my Update 2

Comment: Where do you create the context (`DB`)?  Just because you're not explicitly disposing it doesn't mean it's not being disposed by the framework.  It'll go out of scope and be removed.

Comment: sorry I have included another update to show that.  Since we've got our own inheritance framework it's quite hard to show the relevant details